# Content not displayed when using full-screen Dialog in React Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Following the documentation of material-ui (https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/),
I see that the dialog can be full screen. However, when I use it with `AppBar` and `ToolBar`, the `DialogContent` does not get displayed.

Below is the code for my dialog.

```
<Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
    Open full-screen dialog
</Button>
<Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose} TransitionComponent={Transition}>

    <AppBar style={{ backgroundColor: "#182026" }} className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose} aria-label="close">
                <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                Sound
            </Typography>
        </Toolbar>

    </AppBar>

<DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText>
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
            Google, even when no apps are running.
        </DialogContentText>
    </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

This just gives me

[image]

When I inspect this, I can see that the content is hidden inside the header which is pretty weird.

Since this code is mostly from the demo, I am not sure how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-cp6g9. Please create a sandbox that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add position relative to your app bar class.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
appBar: {
    position: 'relative',
},
title: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    flex: 1,
},
```

}));

And on the actual appear apply

```
<AppBar className={classes.appBar} />
```